# Flutter: Exception using Navigator.of(context).pop();

Tags: flutter, exception, view, navigator

Every time I use `Navigator.of(context).pop();` to return to the previous view I always get the

> Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'call' was called
> on null.

message.

However, the app successfully goes back to the previous view, but I don't know why I always get this message that sometimes causes a crash. What could it be?

```
#0      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
#1      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
#2      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
#3      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
#4      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
#5      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
#6      Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
#7      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
#8      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
#9      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
#10     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
#11     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#12     _startMicrotaskLoop<…>
```

I usually use an Inkwell associated with an icon to call the method. In example:

```
InkWell(onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(), 

  child: Icon(Icons.chevron_left_rounded, color: Constants.COLOR_DEF, size: 30));
```

Comment: Please provide some code related to your call method.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, found the problem.

Basically, when going from one page to another, I've always called "Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute)" passing also a callback function (if necessary). When that callback function is not passed (null) the error is thrown.

Thanks anyway to anyone who replied!

Answer (score 0):

this error usually arrives when the `Navigator.of(context).currentState` is `null`

which means you don't have any `Route` below current route, so you can't pop the route.
Check this do you have any route below this route or not??

Comment: Yes I do, because even with this error the app goes back to the previous page.
However, when I go from one page to another I always push a new MaterialPageRoute: 
Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => dest, settings: RouteSettings(name: "/" + routeName))).then(callbackFunction);

Comment: ok than I would need some more code related to this problem, if you can provide that would be great or else I would be blind shooting 